# Airflow: How to pass a variable in json / dict format to an operator?

Tags: json, python-3.x, variables, jinja2, jinja2-cli

I need to know how to pass a registered dictionary as a variable in the parameters of an operator to launch a databricks notebook, for example.

In my case I have tried some things but not works.

I have this variable saved in Airflow:

```
"dictionaries" : {
                     "dict1" : {
                                "a" : 1,
                                "b" : 2
                               }
```

and this code to try to retrieve the variable

```
dict = "dict1"
values = f"{{{{ var.json.dictionaries.{dict} }}}}"
```

to later pass it as a dictionary along with other values in the parameters of an operator

```
task1 = DatabricksRunNowOperator(
            task_id=f'Databricks_{dict1}',
            databricks_conn_id='databricks',
            job_id= 1111,
            notebook_params={"param1": "param1" , **values}
```

This is failing because the variable comes as str "TypeError: 'str' object is not a mapping", so I have tried to use the json library to try to convert the format but I have not been successful, I get the error message "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"

So I suspect that it may be retrieving the variable with single quotes, I have also tried using replace to try to change them to doubles but that didn't work either.

```
json.loads(values.replace("'","\""))
```

Being using jinja to retrieve this variable may not behave the same, I'm a bit lost with this, I have tried last

```
values = json.loads(f"{{{{ (var.json.dictionaries.{dict1}).replace('\'','\"') }}}}")
values = json.loads((f"{{{{ var.json.dictionaries.{dict1} }}}}").replace('\'','\"'))
```

also inside the operator

```
notebook_params={"param1": "param1", **json.loads((f"{{{{ var.json.dictionaries.{dict1} }}}}").replace('\'','\"'))}
```

but get the same error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"

Surely i am misinterpreting the way to recover the variable and transform it, if someone can help me with this I would appreciate it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to save the variable's value as shown below:

```
{
 "dictionaries" : {
                   "dict1" : {
                             "a" : 1,
                             "b" : 2
                            }
                   }
}
```

And when you access the variable in the code, pass the deserialize_json=True.
Lets say your variable was called 'json' then,

```
from airflow.models import Variable
json_data = Variable.get('json', deserialize_json=True)
dict1 = json_data['dictionaries']['dict1']
```